# Python - attribute error (running script on different PC)

Tags: python, email, outlook

Complete beginner here. 
Below script runs fine on PC1, but not on PC2. I receive the below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sgreene\Documents\indices.py", line 44, in <module>
    if msg.SentOn.strftime('20%y-%m-%d') == str(date.today() + datetime.timedelta(lagdays)):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: <unknown>.SentOn
```

As far as I know, both versions of pypiwin32 (win32com) are the same on both PCs, (version 223), so I am unsure as to how to deal with this.

Note: I also am looking to search a particular mail folder. At the moment I have it set to the default inbox (6). How do I make the script search a specifically named mail folder?

```
            from win32com.client import Dispatch
            import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
            from datetime import date
            import pandas as pd
            import datetime
            import openpyxl as px
            import os


            file_location = r'C:\Users\Stefa\Documents\XMLfiles'


            excel_location = r'C:\Users\Stefa\Documents\indices.xlsx'


            sheet_code = 'Sheet1'


            lag = 3

            d = str(date.today())    

            outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
            inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
            all_inbox = inbox.Items
            sub_today = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
            attach_strings = ['CMSIA', 'CMSRA']
            sheet = pd.read_excel(excel_location)
            wb = px.load_workbook(excel_location)
            ws = wb[sheet_code]


            for lagdays in range(-lag,1): 

                day = (date.today() + datetime.timedelta(lagdays)).weekday()
                newfolder = file_location + '\\' + str(date.today() + datetime.timedelta(lagdays))

                if not os.path.exists(newfolder): 
                    if day<5:
                        os.makedirs(newfolder)
                        for i in sub_today:
                            for x in attach_strings:
                                for msg in all_inbox:
                                    if msg.SentOn.strftime('20%y-%m-%d') == str(date.today() + datetime.timedelta(lagdays)):
                                        if msg.Subject == i:          
                                            for att in msg.Attachments:
                                                if x in att.FileName:
                                                    att.SaveAsFile(file_location + '\\' + str(date.today() + datetime.timedelta(lagdays)) + '\\' + i + x + '.xml')   
                                                    tree = ET.parse(file_location + '\\' + str(date.today() + datetime.timedelta(lagdays)) + '\\' + i + x + '.xml')
                                                    root = tree.getroot()
                                                    for child in root:
                                                        for u in range(1,ws.max_column):
                                                            if str(child[1].text) == str(ws.cell(row=1, column=u).value):
                                                                for n in range(1,ws.max_row):
                                                                    if str(ws.cell(row=n, column=1).value) == str(date.today() + datetime.timedelta(lagdays)) + ' 00:00:00':
                                                                        if x == 'CMSIA':
                                                                            ws.cell(row=n, column=u).value = child[4].text
                                                                        else: 
                                                                            ws.cell(row=n, column=u).value = child[2].text

            wb.save(r'C:\Users\Stefa\Documents\SMindices.xlsx')
```

Comment: I'll start by asking - why on earth are there so many nested `for` loops and `if` statements?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am a complete beginner, tasked with making a script within the next day. Unfortunately, I do not know a more efficient way of achieving what I want to achieve. Just need a quick fix for this script so it can work on another PC.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry if I came across as hostile :) If you hadn't guessed already, it's not advisable to do so as it makes the code much less readable, which opens yourself up to having lots of bugs.

Comment: no hostility taken! thanks, I know its quite obnoxious, unfortunately here is my last hope! will avoid posting such scripts again! do you happen to know any reason why msg.'x' would not be working on this particular pc?

Comment: Problem solved. issue with particular emails (bouncebacks) being of different format than normal

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming you only have `MailItem` objects in the Inbox. You can also have `ReportItem` or `MeetingItem` objects - they do not expose the `SentOn` property. Check the `Class` property first (it is exposed by all OOM objects) - for the `MailItem` object, it is 43 (`OlObjectClass.olMail`).

```
for msg in all_inbox:
  if msg.Class = 43 Then
   ...
  End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you!